# Folders redirection in apache

Tags: apache

I have user files stored in a folder outside apache's documents root e.g. My project is in /var/www/ProjectName/ and the files are in local drive(D:\users).

I want to be able to link to those files from within my project. i am using symfony(php framework).

I trying to change the setting in apache like this, But no luck

Alias /users/ "D:\users"
  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

Answer (score 1):

You have to update that in your `httpd.conf` or in your specified `{name of your vhost}.conf`.

```
Alias /users/ D:\users
```

Be sure to check the `error log` to see where here Apache tries to find the files.

Comment: hi, thank u for u r reply. It is working fine, but my requirement is, 1)First, should check the path(contains dynamic images) using the php file_exists()  2)how do you check the file_exists() using 'alias'.

Comment: I am not that sure what you mean ... but I hope I got you right: http://pastie.org/1501835

Comment: Actually checking the image path(image exists or not) like this:   if(file_exists(sfConfig::get('app_image_path').$md5_userid.'/images/'.$sid.'_thumb.png') && filesize(sfConfig::get('app_image_path').$md5_userid.'/images/'.$sid.'_thumb.png') >3)
     $image_path = '/users/'.$md5_userid.'/images/'.$sid.'_thumb.png';        
    else
     $image_path = '/images/assets/icons/dummy.gif';
     return $image_path;}  .The problem is how do you check the file exists using the alias path

Comment: You have to set `app_image_path` in the `sfConfig` to D:\users\ internally. But set the `$image_path` as you are doing here! ;-)

Comment: hay! i got it . Thank u for u r reply